# How to check the version of Build Tools I am using?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have defined the Build Tool version as below in the build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}
```

But I see there is a folder .gradle/2.14.1 created while I build under my Project root.

```
Am i using gradle version 2.2.2 or 2.14.1??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
```

defines the gradle plugin for Android.

**Do not confuse it with the gradle version.**
You can specify the Gradle version used by each project editing the Gradle distribution reference in the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

For example:

```
...
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
...
```

Comment: Update the answer for finding which build tools vesion is used .Im searching for that only